# how to display array values in webpage from knockout js array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How will i be able to display the array  values of `FileList` using foreach inside a div? and reiterate the items one by one?

[image: here's the screenshot of the array]

**dataservice code:**

var GetUploads = function (GetUploadsObservable) {

```
        var Importoptions = {
            url: 'api/test/GetUploads',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        };

        return $.ajax(Importoptions).then(GetDataSucceded).fail(queryFailed);

        function GetDataSucceded(data) {
            var Filelist = [];
            if (data != null) {
                data.forEach(function (item) {
                    Filelist.push(new model.FolderFiles(item));
                });
            }
            GetUploadsObservable(Filelist);
            //alert("YYYY");
            console.log(Filelist);
        }
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="timesheet" class="" data-bind="foreach: Filelist" style="border:solid 1px red;">

                </div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Here's the foreach reference if it helps. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit vague, but if I'm understanding you correctly you're trying to loop through a list of files which you get from some kind of service.

Your file list variable is a local function array therefore isn't available to be bound to the view. What you might want to try is to bind to 'GetUploadsObservable' instead, and make sure GetUploadsObservable is part of your view model. See example below:

```
<div id="timesheet" class="" data-bind="foreach: GetUploadsObservable" style="border:solid 1px red;"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></div>
```

Please see this link for more info on $data: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html